# Trying to insert data into various tables via stored procedure, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, plsql, pega

I am trying to get a JAVA program (Pega to be exact) to call the procedure to load XML data by calling a stored procedure, but it is not working, what am i doing wrong? I know it has something to do with my variable definitions but i am not sure how i would be able to specify that they will be provided parameters by the java file. below is my stored procedure. Thanks in advance

The error messages I'm getting are:

> Error(2,16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: := . ) , @ % default character

and

> Error(16,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior

```
Create or Replace Procedure Cascade_Load (
    Value_ID Number,
    pValue_ID Number,
    pCalculation_ID Number,
    Calculation_ID Number,
    Calculation_Value_ID Number,   
    p_Entity_Address_ID Varchar2(50),
    New_Value_ID Number,
    New_Calculation_ID Number,
    New_Calculation_Value_ID Number
) AS
    BEGIN
        IF code is not null
        THEN
            INSERT INTO Value (Value_ID, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, 
                value_tx, padd_cd, supply_type_id, country_cd, state_cd, county_cd, 
                entity_address_id,  series_id, energy_process_cd, result_type_cd, 
                geo_area_cd, create_dt, create_user_id)
            VALUES ( 
                Value_ID, 
                Get_energy_product_id(:NEW.Product_Name_Cd),
                Get_Data_Source_Id(:NEW.Data_Source_Tx),
                :NEW.UNIT_CD ,
                :NEW.Value_Tx,
                :NEW.PADD_CD,
                Get_Supply_Type_Id(:NEW.Supply_Type_Tx),
                :NEW.COUNTRY_CD,
                Get_State_CD(Get_entity_Id(p_Entity_Address_ID)),
                'NA',
                Get_Entity_Address_ID(Get_Entity_ID(p_Entity_Address_ID)),
                0,
                :NEW.Energy_Process_CD,
                :NEW.Result_Type_CD,
                :NEW.Geo_Area_Cd,
                Sysdate,
                '15'
            );
            Commit;
            END IF;
            END;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: added them to my original question, sorry

Comment: Is that your complete procedure?

Comment: It looks like you are using trigger code in a stored procedure?

Comment: yes, i am very lost on how i can simply have JAVA call my stored procedure with very specific parameters and have my stored procedure run aftger being called. DO you know any useful guides out there that can give me better direction on this?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Oracle doesn't use T-SQL!

Comment: You cannot use :NEW.UNIT_CD in a procedure. You need to replace all such values with the variables that you created at the top of the procedure. `:NEW` is only for triggers where you have a new row of data coming in.

Answer (score 0):

@icerabbit

Am not sure if it is a syntax error for having semicolons to separate parameters instead of comas. If this was the case You would've got an error message while compiling itself.
What is that code in the body of the SP, is that a variable which is not defined? 
If Value is a table name, try enclosing it in the braces.
If you are seeing an error message, please post that too, it'll give some idea for debugging further.

Thank you

Comment: I fixed what you suggested, now i am getting bad bind variable errors. I assumed if NEW is a pre-existing function/class in the system how can i import in at the beginning of the code? (if that makes any sense)

Comment: If your intending to just make an insert into the table with values you receiving as parameter plus values you generate from different stored procedures it is always good to follow few standards. First define all parameters with p_ as prefixes just to remove ambiguity between parameters and column names. Secondly declare variables - number of variables should be equal to the number of columns you are trying to insert in this SP. Thirdly define all these variables with values you wanting to insert them with like v_col1 = p_col1 and v_col2 = getCol2(p_col2) and then use these just defined variab

Comment: ➕ Just defined variables in your insert statement in the SP

Comment: if java / pega is calling my stored procedure do i just leave the variables declared but not defined? (I.e. Value_ID Number) Not quite sure how this works or if there are any guides out there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the semicolon  with comma in your stored procedure's parameters

Answer (score 0):

:NEW and :OLD variables are used just in TRIGGERS.

You can't BIND then inside a stored procedure.